# Is the cardinal of a subset of random variable a random variable?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, independence, median

Here is my problem :
$Z_i$  a sequence of i.i.d. random variables on the same probability space with median k.

$M_n = |{i = 1 . . . n : Z_i ≤ k}|$ and $P_n = |{i = 1 . . . n : Z_i > k}|$.

Can we describe $L_n$ as a sum of i.i.d. random variables?
Is $M_n$  a random variable? If yes how can we describe it with the $Z_i$?
Does $M_n/n$ converge as $n → ∞$ ?
Does $n^{−1/2}(M_n − P_n)$ converge in law as $n → ∞$ ?
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer to get you started. You can describe $M_n$ and $P_n$ as sums of iid **indicator random variables**: For instance, if we set $I_i = \cases{1 {\text { if } } Z_i\le k\\0{\text { otherwise } }}$, then $M_n = I_1 + \cdots + I_n$. This is a common construction, for example the binomial distribution is a sum of iid Bernoulli random variables, which each itself can be thought as an indicator random variable. We have $M_n/n$ converge in probability to the expected value of $I_i$, which is $E(I_i)=P(Z_i\le k)$. See weak law of large numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Also note, $M_n + P_n = n$, so $M_n - P_n = n- 2P_n$, this may be helpful to analyze your other question.